# Authenticating with Youtube from Android

Tags: android

I want to be able to authenticate a user account with youtube from my android appliation so that i can get the list of favourate videos or other account information of the associate account. Is there any API Available. How can i do it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api). Using this API in your app, you can "perform many of the operations available on the YouTube website", which includes being able to "authenticate as a user to upload videos, modify user playlists, and more." From the link I provided, there is documentation for versions 2.0 and 3.0. For the more discerning programmer, there are also oodles of [sample codes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#sample_code) available.

Comment: Youtube data API is not available for android i guess.. i went through these articals earlier but found nothing. Have tried it ?

Comment: There's a [developer's guide for Java](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java). As long as you include the API in your project and export it into the APK, there is no reason it won't work in your app.